# Passing data from one form to another

Tags: html, forms

very new to HTML, CSS, JS.

I wanted to know if it's possible to pass data from 1 Form to another.

Example if I had a page with Multiple Search Boxes, they user would only need to type in their search once.

Search 1 [Type your Search Here] [Submit]

Search 2 [Copies search from Search 1] [Submit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript to add an `input` event listener that assigns the value of the input to the value of all other fields (identified with the class `copied-content`).

```js
const otherSearchBars = document.querySelectorAll('.copied-content');
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function(){
  const c = this;
  otherSearchBars.forEach(e=>e.value = c.value);
})
```

```html
Search 1 <input> <button>Submit</button>
<hr>
Search 2 <input class="copied-content"> <button>Submit</button>
<hr>
Search 3 <input class="copied-content"> <button>Submit</button>
```